# include a variable from a QlineEdit in a QTextEdit via a QPushbutton

Tags: qt, qstring, qtextedit, qlineedit

I am looking to include a variable from a `QLineEdit` in a `QTextEdit` with a `QPushButton`. I imagine that this is a silly mistake on my part but after research I can not find a solution.

here is my code:

```
void MainWindow::on_prenomLineEdit_editingFinished()
{
    QString const inputPrenom = ui->prenomLineEdit->text();
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked(const QString& inputPrenom)
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(QString ("prenom: %1").arg(inputPrenom));
}
```

So how to fix it?
Thank you for helping me.

Comment: I'm not really sure if i understood what you are trying to achieve. But wouldn't it be easier to just assign the text from line edit to text edit if you press the button using `ui->textEdit->setText(QString ("prenom: %1").arg(ui->prenomLineEdit->text()));` and remove the function parameter `inputPrenom` from `on_pushButton_2_clicked()`.

Comment: The assignment of `ui->prenomLineEdit->text()` to `inputPrenom` in `on_prenomLineEdit_editingFinished()` makes no sense as `inputPrenom` is just created on stack and will be destroyed on function exit.